# How to compare entries in one file to two files?

Tags: shell

I have a file (named file1) which consists of names and their IPs. It looks something like this :-

```
VM1 2.33.4.22
VM2 88.43.21.34
VM3 120.3.45.66
VM4 99.100.34.5
VM5 111.3.4.66
```

and i have two files (file2 and file3) which consists solely of IPs.

File 2 consists of:-

```
120.3.45.66
88.43.21.34
```

File 3 consists of :-

```
99.100.34.5
```

I want to compare file1 to file2 and file3 and get the names and IPs that are not present in file2 and file3. So output would be:

```
VM1 2.33.4.22
VM5 111.3.4.66
```

How can i get the desired output?

Comment: Will files 2 and 3 get much bigger (more than 10 lines for example)?

Comment: @Kendle yes. They exceed much more than 10. Close to 200 i would imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\./\\./g; s/.*/ &$/' file2 file3 | grep -vf - file1
```

- Use sed to turn the entries in files 2 and 3 in to appropriate regexes.
- Pipe this regex list to grep, with `-f -` to get the pattern list from standard input, and `-v` to print *non* matching lines in file 1.

Comment: I don't think you even need to convert `file2` and `file3` to proper regexen. This works for me:

`cat file2 file3 | grep -vf - file1`

Comment: No, they need to be anchored at the beginning (I use a space) and end (`$` - end of line). Otherwise they can match anywhere in the line, and it fails for example with`1.2.3.4` (IP list) and `VM4 111.2.3.4` (name and IP list). Also, `.` is regex for "any character", so it must be escaped to get a literal dot.

Comment: Ah, right. It works for this particular sample, but it would break for other cases. Good catch.

Comment: @Frost I probably could have explained the regex better. But now I have. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I understand regex well enough. I just forgot that `grep` always matches by regex. By some reason I thought it only did string comparisons by default. That was wrong of me, and I should know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script that will do it for you.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $1.txt $2.txt > mergedFile.txt
grep -v -f mergedFile.txt $3.txt
```

You can run the script by using the following command
`sh check.sh file2 file3 file1`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { out[$1]=1; next} !out[$2]' <(/bin/cat file2 file3) file1
```

This uses basically the same thing as the `sed` solution, using `awk` instead.